# Há como mudar o manifest.mf direto do eclipse?

Tags: java

Bom, preciso setar o Class-Path do manifest.mf no eclipse, pra que quando eu compile ele já fique assim, pois atualmente toda vez que eu compilo tenho que alterar no jar.

é possível? se sim, como?

Comment: Consegui, caso alguem tenha a mesma dúvida de uma olhada aqui http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-35.htm

Comment: Seria interessante você responder sua pergunta, links podem ficar offline.

Comment: É o link do site oficial de ajuda do eclipse, acho meio difícil de ficar offline...

Comment: E o link nao funciona mais...